# How will a common guy use Lightning Network when BTC hits 10 mln$?

Tags: transaction-fees, lightning-network, economic-theory, micropaymentchannels

If BTC hits 10mln$ and transactions fees will be horrendous denominated in $, how a "common guy" will be able to opt in using Bitcoin, if even opening LN channel will be too expensive then since it requires on-chain payment? As I understand the only way for him would be to rely on third party which would'nt be very different from using a bank.

Comment: Also see this related question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/87843/5406

Answer (score 1):

I assume that people will have more refined ideas by the time this would actually appear on the horizon, but here are some ideas:

- [channel factories](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/67187/5406)
- Custodial Lightning Wallets, i.e. "Lightning banks"
- atomic swap from a payment focused sidechain
- purchasing spendable LN balance on other users' Lightning nodes via [macaroons](https://blog.lightning.engineering/announcement/2020/01/22/lnd-v0.9.html#security) that permit spending a specific amount

Or more generally, I suspect that people would develop third layer solutions that permit multiple users to share Lightning Network channels effectively.